# Jquery Dialog button Calling Page In FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a href tag and i am calling a form in fancybox. This is how its done;

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" caption ="Registration" href="registration.htm">Registration</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link the page opens in **fancybox**. I have now implemented a **jquery** dialog  with buttons and i am attempting to call the registration page just as above when the user clicks on a button in the dialog box. How can this be achieved? This is what i have thus far:

**Jquery Dialog:**

```
$( "#userOptions-dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        width: 380,
        resizable:false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );},

            "Register": function() {
                //how can i call the href tag here          
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me added css to hide the link and used simple javascript call to click on the link.

**html**

```
<a id = "registration" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" caption ="Registration" href="registration.htm">Registration</a>
```

**css**

```
#registration{
display:none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$( "#userOptions-dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        width: 380,
        resizable:false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );},

            "Register": function() {
                $("#registration").click();      
            }
    });
```